# Prove that for all integers $ a $ and $ b $, if $ a $ divides $ b $, then $ a^{2} $ divides $ b^{2} $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I just need to know that if $ a $ divides $ b $, where $ a $ and $ b $ are integers, does $ a^{2} $ divide $ b^{2} $?

Answer (score 9):

If $a$ divides $b$, then $b=ka$ for some integer $k$, so $b^2=k^2a^2$ where $k^2$ is an integer.

Comment: How do you prove that k^2 is an integer? Is that by closure?

Comment: @amster27: If you are concerned about whether $ k^{2} $ is an integer, then you should be equally concerned about whether both $ a^{2} $ and $ b^{2} $ are integers. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just starting to write proofs in a Mathematical Reasoning class, and I just feel so lost. But these explanations helped.

Comment: @amster: Note that $ +_{\mathbb{Z}}: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} $ and $ \times_{\mathbb{Z}}: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} $. Therefore, adding two integers or multiplying two integers yields an integer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ a\mid b\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{b}a\in \Bbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{b^2}{a^2} = \left(\dfrac{b}a\right)^2\!\in \Bbb Z^2\subseteq \Bbb Z\:\Rightarrow\: a^2\mid b^2\ $

Comment: That's closer to a proof than a hint.

Comment: The argument is elegant, but I think that the OP wants to stay within $ \mathbb{Z} $ and does not wish to jump into $ \mathbb{Q} $, as he seems to be very interested in the axioms governing the properties of $ \mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: @Haskell Possibly, but there was no hint of any such constraint in the question.