# If $3\mid a$, then $3\mid a^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility

I want to prove for all integers $a$ that if $3\mid a$ then $3\mid a^2$.

Suppose that $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mid a$. Then $a = 3k$ for any integer k. 
Hence
$$a^2 = (3k)(3k) = 9k^2 = 3(3k^2)$$

Since $k$ is a integer, $3k^2$ is an integer. Thus $a^2 = 3b$ for some integer $b$. 
Therefore $3\mid a^2$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You haven't typed out any question. This is a Q&A website where you ask questions. If you want us to check your work, then say so.

Comment: Proof is absolutely correct.  But is long as you a proving it, you should prove the much,much more general: if $m|a$ then $m|ka $ for all $k$.  Then just set $m=3$ and $k=a$.  In fact i'I'd be very surprised if this wasn't a result you are supposed to know cold and $3|a \implies 3|a^2$ was simply supposed to be an obvious application and not a proof in its on right.

Comment: What does the symbol $|$ mean?

Comment: @IanMiller Comments are the right place for a question that helps to understand the OP. So it is the right place about the meaning of a symbol used in the OP.

Comment: For *some* integer $\,k,\,$ not *any*. The rest is fine. More generally you can prove that $\,d\mid a\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid ab,\,$ i.e. multiples of $\,d\,$ are closed under multiplication by *any* integer $\,b.\ $ Further you can show they are closed under addition, so under linear combinations.

Comment: To be honest, I am not entirely sure that this should [be considered a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1905056/revisions) of [Prove that for all integers $a$ and $b$, if $a$ divides $b$, then $a^{2}$ divides $b^{2}$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/310758). If not for any other reason, proving that $9\mid a^2$ is stronger than proving $3\mid a^2$. (In fact, in this question it suffices to use transitivity: we have $3\mid a$ and $a\mid a^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is absolutely correct. That is the usual way to prove this. You can simply extend the this to prove

If $c|a$ then $c|a^2$.

And in a similar manner you can prove that $c^2|a^2$